# How to get all data from a particular json key android kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a json response like this:

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 3,
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "604b266e7e2dd800159031e4",
        "type": "expense",
        "description": "This is an income",
        "amount": 4555,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-12T08:29:34.128Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-12T08:29:34.128Z",
        "id": "604b266e7e2dd800159031e4"
    },
    {
        "_id": "604b24ac7e2dd800159031e2",
        "type": "expense",
        "description": "This is an income",
        "amount": 4555,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-12T08:22:04.802Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-12T08:22:04.802Z",
        "id": "604b24ac7e2dd800159031e2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "604b24897e2dd800159031e1",
        "type": "income",
        "description": "This is an income",
        "amount": 4555,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-12T08:21:29.684Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-12T08:21:29.684Z",
        "id": "604b24897e2dd800159031e1"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a **"type"** key in the object array whose value can either be *"expense"* or *"income"*.

Now, in my android, how do I get only data for "expense" and "income" NOT all of them.

Example I want to run this request but get only the type whose value is "expense". How do I do it with Kotlin?

I am using Retrofit

```
Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {

  if (it.data?.status == "success") {

       for (expenditureType in it.data.data){

                val type = expenditureType.type
               //logic here 

            }
       } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val expenseList = it.data.data.filter { it.type = "expense" }
```

It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of all types,

you can get list of string using map function.

```
  val list:List<String> = it.data.data.map {
      it.type
  }
```

If you want a filtered list with specific types,

```
val list = it.data.data.filter {
      it.type == "expense" or it.type == "income"
}
```